# Bash variables in command

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, xrandr

I would like to make this command `xrandr -s 640x480` use variables like so

```
#!/bin/bash

display_x=640
display_y=480

xrandr -s $display_xx$display_y
```

The command does not run correctly. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

display_x=640
display_y=480

xrandr -s ${display_x}x${display_y}
```

Comment: Oh, braces, I saw that somewhere online.  Thank you sir.

Answer (score 2):

You should always put shell variables into quotes
unless you have a good reason not to,
and you’re sure you know what you’re doing. 
So [Deathgrip’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/384621/23408#384623) should be

```
xrandr -s "${display_x}x${display_y}"
```

and that is the way I would probably do it. 
But

```
xrandr -s "$display_x"x"$display_y"
```

will also work. 
Here’s another approach:

```
display_x=640
display_y=480
x=x
xrandr -s "$display_x$x$display_y"
```

— anything to tell the shell
that you’re not trying to reference a variable named `display_xx`.